# How exposed is user data when running PINENTRY_USER_DATA="foo" gpg --change-pin?

Tags: gnupg, bash

When running `PINENTRY_USER_DATA="foo" gpg --change-pin` in bash, how easy is it for other processes to capture “foo”?

Answer (score 2):

That syntax in bash sets the specified environment variable for the program you are running. Environment variables for a particular program can be read at `/proc/<pid>/environ`. This means any other processes running as the same user or a user with root privileges can trivially read this value.

To mitigate this, your best bet is to run the process under a different user account. That account may be privileged or not, depending on your needs, but at least separate from other accounts that are untrusted. Ultimately, you cannot hide this type of information from the system/root.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Would you happen to know (or have ideas on) how to mitigate this?

Comment: @sunknudsen added something.

Answer (score 1):

If a program is actively trying to grab `foo`, it can by searching all processes from the same user, and search `environ` for any variable. This program must run with the same user as you, or from a privileged account. If `alice` is running `gpg`, `eve` cannot do this with her common user account.

This program would have to keep an active search for every new process launch, see if it's `gpg`, and dump its `environ` file. But the window to use the old pin is pretty small.

As you will change the PIN immediately, the old PIN loses its utility pretty fast. As soon as you enter the new PIN, the old one is useless.

Another look at this: if you are worried about another process running as you and grabbing the environment variables from GPG, you are worrying about the wrong thing. A malicious process running as you can just attach `gdb` to whatever process you run, dump its memory, inject data.

So if there's something malicious running as you on the system, don't try to hide from it. Nuke the system and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Btw, I am planning on running this on Tails without persistence so I believe environment is safe. That said, I am very thankful for your answers. They really help me understand the implications of using environment variables.

Comment: If you use Tails for it, you are reasonably secure.